# IPtables block range with exception

Tags: linux, tcp, ip, firewall, iptables

I have a server in my network for which I want to DROP outbound traffic to any other host in the LAN, except for one or 2 single hosts. E.g. I want to block outbound traffic to 123.123.1.1/16, except for 123.123.10.10 and 123.123.20.20. How can I do this in IPTABLES?

I have tried something like this:

```
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -d 123.123.1.1/16 ! -d 123.123.10.10 -j DROP
```

However I get an error that the `-d` operator can only be used once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do an `ACCEPT` before the `DROP`.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 123.123.10.10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 123.123.1.1/16 -j DROP
```

That way once the packet matches the first rule it won't even be tested against the second.